# IBM speech-to-text username and password issue

Tags: python, ibm-cloud, watson-assistant

I'm working on an AI assistant, and for text-to-speech recognition in Python I used google, but it's way to slow and not really accurate. So I created an account in IBM and get text-to-speech credentials, but as you can see the format asks for the input, username and password but IBM migrated to API keys.

I don't know what should I put in username and password since I only have the key.
What should I put there?

[image: AI Text to speech]

Comment: Your API key is a secret which is now publicly-available! You should recreate it or _anyone_ who sees this can use it!

Comment: I did!  the API key that I show is fake, but thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, there is a new IAM Authenticator wrapper / package / module which handles authentication for the services. You can see the IAM Authenticator in this [Python text-to-speech sample](https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/python-sdk/blob/master/examples/text_to_speech_v1.py).

If you happen to use some API which requires username and password, then use **apikey** as username and the API key as password.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response!:), I tried using "apikey" as username and the service credential API key as password but it doesn't seem to work, it doest pop any error but it just freezes. this is my code: speech = r.recognize_ibm(input, username="apikey", password= "zEcMt01NR1tX7z82_XXxxXxxXSPKe-ylT-GxdjrTYQoXZEy4")
am I doing something wrong?

Comment: it gives me this error
ssl.SSLCertVerificationError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self signed certificate in certificate chain (_ssl.c:1123)

Comment: What library / module is `r.recognize_ibm` based on? It is not the IBM Watson module

Comment: it's speech_recognition

Comment: mark this answer complete and ask a new question regarding the SSL cert issue - and make it clear that you are using this one https://github.com/Uberi/speech_recognition/ (I guess)