# Speech Recognition(IBM) username and password

Tags: python, ibm-cloud, speech-recognition, speech-to-text

I hope to use IBM speech recognition service without `- curl` or `ibm_watson` module.
And my attempt is below:

```
import speech_recognition as sr
r = sr.Recognizer()
text = r.recognize_ibm(audio,username='',password='')
```

Even though, I have 'Service credentials' for IBM cloud - speech to text, I cannot find correct form for the function.
In the documents of `recognize_ibm()`, it is said that I need to enter the [link_1](https://www.ibm.com/watson/developercloud/doc/getting_started/gs-credentials.shtml) to find my `username` in `XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX` format.
But the link_1 is broken.
Where can I find the `username` and `password`?

I also tried `text = r.recognize_ibm(audio,username='apikey',password=api_key)` as the previous answers [link_2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64357232/ibm-speech-to-text-username-and-password-issue).

Actually I realized the module was not working.

Comment: First question: why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are the official API docs for Speech to Text: https://cloud.ibm.com/apidocs/speech-to-text

It includes various samples and further links. You can use the [IAMAuthenticator](https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/python-sdk#iam) to turn an API key into an authentication token and to handle refresh tokens. If you don't want to make use of the SDK you have to deal with the [IBM Cloud IAM Identity Service API](https://cloud.ibm.com/apidocs/iam-identity-token-api) on your own. The API has functions to obtain authentication / access tokens.

I often use a function like this to turn an API key into an access token:

```
def getAuthTokens(api_key):
    url     = "https://iam.cloud.ibm.com/identity/token"
    headers = { "Content-Type" : "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" }
    data    = "apikey=" + api_key + "&grant_type=urn:ibm:params:oauth:grant-type:apikey"
    response  = requests.post( url, headers=headers, data=data )
    return response.json()
```

You could

Comment: If previous experience is any indication, these links too will break. IBM is notoriously bad at keeping things where they put them.

Comment: From my experience, IBM has changed doc locations over time (years). It's within "industry standards"...